# what is the use of FACTORY_BEAN_PREFIX = "&" in BeanFactory?

Tags: spring

i am new to `spring` and want to know the purpose of  `FACTORY_BEAN_PREFIX = "&"` field of `bean factory`. Anyone please explain.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Framework for Dependency Injection provides some component to encapsulate complex objects initialization and population. It is `FactoryBean`. So, you can do something like this:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.my.proj.MyBeanFactoryBean"/>
```

Where `MyBeanFactoryBean` creates and return `MyBean`. From here Spring container populates `MyBean` object under `myBean` `id`.

But for some reason the `MyBeanFactoryBean` is populated to the container as a bean, too.
And here `FACTORY_BEAN_PREFIX` comes to the rescue and it is registered with id `&myBean`.

From your application you can get access to that bean by `id` and container returns for you the `MyBeanFactoryBean` object.

More info you can find from [Spring Framework Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/).

Comment: Hi Artem,m not able to understand the 3rd line can you explain with some fruitfull example.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, be more specific. Why just don't go ahead with books and documentations? And here is enough start up samples: https://spring.io/guides